# Android middleware c program : Unable to create directory, read-only file system

Tags: android, c, linux, native, middleware

In my middleware application, i need to create several directories and files during the execution, but its not able to do so due to permission errors.

I created a simple program to replicate the scenario:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    struct stat st = {0};

    if (stat("/mnt/demo_folder", &st) == -1) {
        mkdir("/mnt/demo_folder", 0700);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and when I run it, I get `unable to create directory /mnt/demo_folder : Read-only file system`.

One way to solve this is below.

Manually, i can run `mount -o remount ,rw /` once on the device and my application never have permission problems in the future. But since i do not have access to end-user devices, i can execute this command using `system()` in the application itself at the beginning. But will that be the proper way? Can anyone point out the best practice in such scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that is not the correct approach.

The end user devices system folder will be in read only. Running the mount command via system will leave the device in a very vulnerable state and I am not sure if android would allow you to run `mount` command.

The correct approach would -

- Declare external storage write permission [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`] in your app. So users will be aware that this app will write to device storage.
- Or use internal storage, but the correct path needs to be queried from app and sent to native. See [Saving Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) from Android documentation.
- Create a new folder in external directory with a name which clearly identifies that it is from your app, so users will know what that folder is for when they view files and folders from other apps
- You should write all your files and folders into the folder you created in the previous folder.